# WSO2 IS SSO structure

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

we trying to add structure for SSO using WSO2, In WSO2 we need to create general Roles and connect this roles with Service provider (Please note service provider doesn't has custom roles so connection will be on service provider level with WSO2 general roles) , in WSO2 we found way to mapping SP roles with WSO2 roles but that not help us, and ,the structure in image below :

[image]

Comment: what protocol are you trying to use? OAuth? SAML?  Unfortunately from the text it is not very clear what exactly is tbe problem you are trying to solve

Comment: we use OAuth but the problem not with the protocols , my issue is how to map external SP with WSO2 roles

Comment: what do you mean by `map external SP with WSO2 roles`? do you need to authorize access to SP? or return roles in the userifo? The wso2is can only return information or authorization decisions (through the XACML entitlement service) , the SP must enforce permissions by itself

Answer (score 0):

Beleive you are saying that your SP application does not persist or maintain the roles, rather you want WSO2 server to do so.

And you want to control authorization based on the availability of these roles for an user.

In that case, WSO2 server has no value nor need to know of the permissions you've assigned to these roles. You just define all the roles you want in the WSO2 server.  Then (given that you use Oauth) by using scopes (mapped against each or multiple roles) to define access levels, you can issue access tokens to the users with the relevant scopes (defines access levels) after checking for the roles assigned to them.

On the resource server, it can validate the scopes of the provided access token against the Identity Server and grant or deny resource availability.

Cheers